# How to remove empty associative array entries

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have an associative array: `$csv_arr`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Enfalac] => alpha linolenic acid 300 mg
            [Enfapro] => alpha linolenic acid 200 mg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Enfalac] => arachidonic acid 170 mg
            [Enfapro] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Enfalac] => 
            [Enfapro] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Enfalac] => calcium 410 mg
            [Enfapro] => calcium 550 mg
        )
)
```

How can I remove all completely empty entries such as `$csv_arr[2]` but preserve partial entries such as `$csv_arr[1]`

I've tried `$csv_arr = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $csv_arr));` but this removes the empty element: `$csv_arr[1]['Enfapro']`

Thx

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like looping? Or array_filter maybe?

Comment: I prefer not to use a loop if at all possible as this is a very large array so a built in function would be preferable. I understand if this isn't possible but I live in hope.

Comment: Loop through the arrays then again loop through the value containing arrays and check if value is null and then unset it.

Comment: Will the inner arrays always have just those two elements?

Comment: There could be as many as 200 elements but essentially it's a variable number of elements. If it helps I will know the count of these keys beforehand.

Comment: as this says http://stackoverflow.com/a/6569117/281996 there is no lazy array iterating in php

Comment: Try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66004034/7186739

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this, a little weird, but :

```
array_filter($csv_arr, function($v){return array_filter($v) == array();});
```

Completely untested and I don't remember if this is the proper syntax or not for closures, but it could work.

Edit (tested and working):

```
<?php
$csv_arr = array(
    0 => array(
            'Enfalac' => 'alpha linolenic acid 300 mg',
            'Enfapro' => 'alpha linolenic acid 200 mg'
        ),

    1 =>  array(
            'Enfalac' => 'arachidonic acid 170 mg',
            'Enfapro' => ''
        ),

    2 =>  array(
            'Enfalac' => '',
            'Enfapro' => ''
        ),

    3 =>  array(

            'Enfalac' => 'calcium 410 mg',
            'Enfapro' => 'calcium 550 mg'
        )
);
$c = function($v){
    return array_filter($v) != array();
};
var_dump(array_filter($csv_arr, $c));
?>
```

Comment: I like the idea but my PHP said no and I wasn't sure how to fix it so I went with an implode variation. Thx tho

Comment: @AndyGee Just for the sake of getting my example right I'll re write it in a more version friendly format.

Comment: @AndyGee Try this, it might be faster than your method, no clue.

Comment: Funny, my benchmarks said yours was faster, maybe it's because I was just using the sample to benchmark it?

Answer (score 8):

In your case it might be even easier. I recently had the same issue. Just use

```
$csv_arr = array_filter($csv_arr, 'array_filter');
```

[array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) removes elements from the array which [bool convert to false](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting). This includes - for example - each of `[], null, '', 0, false`.

**What it does**

1. The first `array_filter()` takes each of the sub-arrays and throws it in the second `array_filter()`.
2. The second `array_filter()` removes every `false` element and returns the rest. Its important to notice that the returned array will become empty if every element converts to `false`.
3. The first `array_filter()` takes the result from the second and checks against `false`. So, in case an empty array is returned the sub-array will be removed from the array.

To prove the case I took the example from John V. and used the single `array_filter()` line:

```
<?php
$csv_arr = array(
    0 => array(
            'Enfalac' => 'alpha linolenic acid 300 mg',
            'Enfapro' => 'alpha linolenic acid 200 mg'
        ),

    1 =>  array(
            'Enfalac' => 'arachidonic acid 170 mg',
            'Enfapro' => ''
        ),

    2 =>  array(
            'Enfalac' => '',
            'Enfapro' => ''
        ),

    3 =>  array(

            'Enfalac' => 'calcium 410 mg',
            'Enfapro' => 'calcium 550 mg'
        )
);
print_r(array_filter($csv_arr, 'array_filter'));
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated by other users you can use [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) method which filters elements of an array using a callback function, what it does is well described in its documentation:

> Iterates over each value in the **array** passing them to the **callback** function. If the **callback** function returns **true**, the current value from **array** is returned into the result array.

So it means you can pass callback function which can be your own custom function or inbuilt php function as you wish, but here you just want to remove empty arrays then you can use inbuilt function to pass in array_filter's callback.

I suggest you to use **`implode(string $separator, array $array)`** function, *it joins array into string using separator if not separator is passed it joins with empty string*, so **if all values in array will be `empty, null or 0` then it will return `false` and if one of them has value then it will return `true`**, so it will remove empty associative arrays as you want.
we will use it as below:

```
$csv_arr = array_filter($csv_arr, 'implode');
```

what it will do is it passes each element to `implode` function and based on its return value it will keep element or remove it from array, I have provided full example below.

**Full example:**

```
<?php
$csv_arr = array
(
     array
        (
            'Enfalac' => 'alpha linolenic acid 300 mg',
            'Enfapro' => 'alpha linolenic acid 200 mg'
        ),

     array
        (
            'Enfalac' => 'arachidonic acid 170 mg',
            'Enfapro' => ''
        ),

     array
        (
            'Enfalac' => '',
            'Enfapro' => ''
        ),

     array
        (
            'Enfalac' => 'calcium 410 mg',
            'Enfapro' => 'calcium 550 mg'
        ),
);

$csv_arr = array_filter($csv_arr, 'implode');
print_r($csv_arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

This one example is tested and it's working:

```php
   $csv_arr = [
           0 => [
               'Enfalac' => 'alpha linolenic acid 300 mg',
               'Enfapro' => 'alpha linolenic acid 200 mg',
           ],

           1 => [
               'Enfalac' => 'arachidonic acid 170 mg',
               'Enfapro' => '',
           ],

           2 => [
               'Enfalac' => '',
               'Enfapro' => '',
           ],

           3 => [

               'Enfalac' => 'calcium 410 mg',
               'Enfapro' => 'calcium 550 mg',
           ],
       ];

       var_dump(array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $csv_arr)));
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks for the help everyone. I managed to do it like this in a loop.

```
if(implode('',$csv_arr[$i])==''){
    unset($csv_arr[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the better and appropriate solution for this,

here is the code:

```
$arr[0]['id'] = "id1";
$arr[0]['name'] = "testing";
$arr[1]['id'] = "id2";
$arr[1]['name'] = "another";
$arr[2]['id'] = "";
$arr[2]['name'] = "";
$d = array_keys($arr);
foreach($arr as $key=>$values){
    $a = array_keys($values);
    $n = count($a);
    for($i=0,$count=0;$i<$n;$i++){
        if($values[$a[$i]]==NULL){
            $count++;
        }
    }
    if($count==$n){

        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```

If you want this to work for more nested associative arrays, you can implement same in recursive function.

Thanks,
Nirav